# No editar registro dependiento del estatus

Tags: php, html, php5

Realizo un sistema de tickets el cual **funciona por 3 estados 1=PENDIENTE, 3=TERMINADO, 4=CANCELADO.** Mi BD esta modelada para que se inserte por llaves foráneas.

Lo que pretendo que haga, es si ***el ticket esta con el estatus 3=TERMINADO no me permita editar ese ticket***. Esto con el fin de cerrar el ticket y no modificar.

Lo intente realizar por medio de mi UPDATE **pero el problema que me arroja es que si tengo tickets con el estatus 1=PENDIENTE y 4=CANCELADO todos me los cambia con el estatus 3=TERMINADO** y ahi ya no me permite modificarlo (que es lo que necesito que haga pero que no me cambie los tickets de de estatus).
Tambien lo que necesito que haga es que me mande un mensaje avisando que ya no se puede modificar por que esta cerrado el ticket.

Gracias.

**Codigo**

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 if (empty($_POST['mod_id'])) {
           $errors[] = "ID vacío";
        } else if (empty($_POST['title'])){
   $errors[] = "Descripción vacío";
  }   else if (
   !empty($_POST['title'])
   
  ){

  include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos



  $title = $_POST["title"];
  $process_1 = $_POST["process_1"];
  $process_2 = $_POST["process_2"];
  $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
  $priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];
  $turn_id = $_POST["turn_id"];
  $area_id = $_POST["area_id"];
  $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
  $status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
  $final_id = $_POST["final_id"];
  $kind_id = $_POST["kind_id"];
  $id=$_POST['mod_id'];

  $sql = "update ticket set title=\"$title\",category_id=\"$category_id\",priority_id=\"$priority_id\",turn_id=\"$turn_id\",area_id=\"$area_id\",process_1=\"$process_1\",process_2=\"$process_2\",status_id=\"$status_id\", final_id=\"$final_id\",kind_id=\"$kind_id\",updated_at=NOW() where status_id !=3";

  $query_update = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if ($query_update){
    $messages[] = "El ticket ha sido actualizado satisfactoriamente.";
   } else{
    $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
   }
  } else {
   $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
  }
  
  if (isset($errors)){
   
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
     <strong>Error!</strong> 
     <?php
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
       }
      ?>
   </div>
   <?php
   }
   if (isset($messages)){
    
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
       foreach ($messages as $message) {
         echo $message;
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <?php
   }

?>
```

**Estructura tabla status**

```
  status_id     Primaria       int(11)          
  name                         varchar(100)
```

**Estructura tabla ticket**

```
id              Primaria    int(11)
title                           varchar(100)
process_1                   varchar(100)
process_2                       varchar(100)
category_id      Índice         int(11)
priority_id      Índice         int(11) 
turn_id          Índice         int(11)
area_id          Índice         int(11)
user_id          Índice         int(11)
status_id        Índice         int(11)
final_id         Índice         int(11)
kind_id          Índice         int(11)
```

Comment: Haz una consulta antes del update comprobando el estado en que esta. Si es posible modificarlo haz el update directamente sobre el.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si estas mandando el id del estado te recomendaria que hagas lo siguiente:

```
if($status_id != 3){
$query_update = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if ($query_update){
      $messages[] = "El ticket ha sido actualizado satisfactoriamente.";
    } else{
      $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
    }

}else{
 return  $errores [] = "Lo siento, ya no se puede modificar por que esta cerrado el ticket."
}
```

**Agregue un nuevo if que si el estado que le pasas es diferente a 3 entonces te permita actualizar, en caso contrario te retornada un mensaje indicando que ya esta cerrado.**

espero que te ayude, saludos

Comment: @Gozalo Motta Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.